# Update UIViewController after Dismissing Modal Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, modalviewcontroller

I am currently designing the structure for my first iPhone game and ran into a problem. Currently, I have a 'MenuViewController' that allows you to pick the level to play and a 'LevelViewController' where the level is played.

A `UIButton` on the 'MenuViewController' triggers a modal segue to the 'LevelViewController'.

A `UIButton` on the 'LevelViewController' triggers the following method to return to the 'MenuViewController':

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender //complete
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The problem is, I have a `UILabel` on the menu page that prints the number of total points a player has. Whenever I go back to the menu from the level, I want this label to automatically update. Currently, the label is defined programmatically in the 'MenuViewController':

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect pointsFrame = CGRectMake(100,45,120,20);
    UILabel *pointsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:pointsFrame];
    [pointsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %i", self.playerPoints]];
    [self.pointsLabel setTag:-100]; //pointsLabel tag is -100 for id purposes
}
```

self.playerPoints is an integer property of MenuViewController

Is there a way I could update the label? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a property `self.pointsLabel` that points to the UILabel, then you can just call something like `[self.pointsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %i", self.playerPoints]];` to update the label with the new score

Comment: that sounds like it would work. But where do I call it? Right now, if I put NSLog(@"menu loaded") in the the viewDidLoad of my menu view controller, it doesn't relog "menu loaded" after returning to the viewcontroller from the level after dismissModalViewController is called, which means that the viewDidLoad method is not being called at all. Would it work if I called it in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear instead? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, are you sure you're updating the pointsValue property of the MenuViewController from your LevelViewController? Do you have like a `delegate` property on LevelViewController that points to the MenuViewController?

Comment: I don't think I have a delegate property yet on LevelViewController. Would this be the way to create one? '@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AppDelegate> delegate;'

Comment: No, just add a property on LevelViewController like this: `@property (strong, nonatomic) MenuViewController *delegate` and then when you instantiate the LevelViewController from the MenuViewController you do the following: (assuming the new LevelViewController instance is called `levelViewController`) `levelViewController.delegate = self`. Then you present the modal view controller etc. Then in your `(IBAction)back:(id)sender` method you update `self.delegate.playerPoints` with the new player points value, and update the label with the code above.

Answer (score 10):

This is a perfect case for delegation.  When the LevelViewController is done, it needs to fire off a delegate method which is handled in the MenuViewController.  This delegate method should dismiss the modal VC and then do whatever else you need it to do.  The presenting VC should normally handled the dismissal of modal views it presents.

Here is a basic example of how to implement this:

LevelViewController.h (Above the Interface declaration):

```
@protocol LevelViewControllerDelegate
    -(void)finishedDoingMyThing:(NSString *)labelString;
@end
```

Same file inside ivar section:

```
__unsafe_unretained id <LevelViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;
```

Same File below ivar section:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <LevelViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In LevelViewController.m file:

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

Now in the MenuViewController.h, `#import "LevelViewController.h"` and declare yourself as a delegate for the LevelViewControllerDelegate:

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <LevelViewControllerDelegate>
```

Now inside MenuViewController.m implement the delegate method:

```
-(void)finishedDoingMyThing:(NSString *)labelString {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.pointsLabel.text = labelString;
}
```

And then make sure to set yourself as the delegate for the LevelViewController before presenting the modal VC:

```
lvc.delegate = self;  // Or whatever you have called your instance of LevelViewController
```

Lastly, when you are done with what you need to do inside the LevelViewController just call this:

```
[_delegate finishedDoingMyThing:@"MyStringToPassBack"];
```

If this doesn't make sense, holler and I can try to help you understand.

Comment: Could you give me a head start on writing a delegate method? I have a class called AppDelegate.m, and AppDelegate.h is imported into both the MenuViewController and the LevelViewController. And would this method be called inside the MenuViewController file instead since that's the presenting VC? Thanks.

Comment: No relation to what you will be doing.  The AppDelegate is just that, a class that handles Application delegate methods.  What you are needing to do is declare a delegate for a particular protocol.  The example I provided above is what you need (you might have to change it slightly to match your implementation

Answer (score 0):

In your modal view header file, add the property:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL updated;
```

Then in your main view controller, use didViewAppear with something like:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (modalView.updated == YES) {
        // Do stuff
        modalView.updated = NO;
    }
}
```

Where "modalView" is the name of that UIViewController that you probably alloc/init there.

Add more properties if you want to pass more info, like what level the user picked.